# unsure why i am getting these errors in my program

Tags: python

does anyone know why I am getting an expected an indented block at def game():?
also, I am getting an error at the indentation of- play again "y". if you guys could give me any tips as to why these things are happening and if you see anything else please let me know it will be greatly appreciated as always.

```
import random 
def main():
    player1Score = 0
    compScore = 0 

    Intro()
    displayMenu()


def Intro():
    print("Welcome to the League of Rock, Paper, Scissors!")
    print("Where contestants battle it out to see who is the best")


    print("Main Menu")
    print("1 See the rules")
    print("2 play against the computer")
    print("3 play a two player game")
    print("4 Quit")
    decision = int(input("\nEnter choice:"))

    #Input validation
    while decision <= 0 or decision > 4:
        print("'ERROR: You must choose 1,2,3 or 4")
        decision = int(input("Enter your choice:"))

    if decision == 1:
        print("The rules here are simple")
        print("Paper Covers Rock")
        print("Rock smashed Scissors")
        print("Scissors Cut Paper")

    if decision == 4:
        print("Goodbye..Thank you for playing")
    if decision == 2:
        return game()

    if decision == 3:
        return player()

def game():
    player_choice = raw_input('Do you choose rock [r], paper [p], or scissors [s]? ')

    computer_choice = randint(0,2)
    #Rock = 0 Paper = 1 Scissors = 2

    #Player chooses paper, computer chooses rock
    if player_choice == "p" and computer_choice == 0:
        print("Computer chose rock")
        player_won()

    #Player chooses rock, computer chooses scissors
    elif player_choice == 'r' and computer_choice == 2:
        print("Computer chose scissors")
        player_won()

    #Player chooses scissors, computer chooses paper
    elif player_choice == 's' and computer_choice == 1:
        print("Computer chose paper")
        player_won()

    #Computer chooses paper, player chooses rock
    elif player_choice == 'r' and computer_choice == 1:
        print("Computer chose paper")
        computer_won()

    #Computer chooses rock, player chooses scissors
    elif player_choice == 's' and computer_choice == 0:
        print("Computer chose rock")
        computer_won()

    #Computer chooses scissors, player chooses paper
    elif player_choice == 'p' and computer_choice == 2:
        print("Computer chose scissors")
        computer_won()

    #Ties
    elif player_choice == 'r' and computer_choice == 0:
        print("It's a tie!")
        game()

    elif player_choice == 's' and computer_choice == 2:
        print("It's a tie!")
        game()

    elif player_choice == 'p' and computer_choice == 1:
        print("It's a tie!")
        game()

    #Wrong input
    else:
        print("Please try again.")
        game()

def player_won():
    global player_count
    print("You win!")
    player_count += 1
    print("You have ' + str(player_count) + ' point(s).")
    if player_count < 3:
        game()

def computer_won():
    global comp_count
    print("Computer wins!")
    comp_count += 1
    print("Computer has ' + str(comp_count) + ' point(s).")
    if comp_count < 3:
        game()

print("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors! First to 3 points wins it all.")
game()

def player():
   ready = input("Requires two players; Are you ready to play? (y/n) ")
while ready != 'y' and ready != 'n':
    ready = input("Oops, I didn't quite get that.")

def player_1():
     x = input("Player 1 - Pick your mode of attack! ")
     while x != 'Rock'and x !='rock' and x != 'Paper'and x != 'paper'and x != 'scissors'and x !='Scissors':
         x = input("Oops, that won't do you any good... ")
     return x

def player_2():
    x = input("Player 2 - Pick your mode of attack! ")
    while x != "Rock" and x != "rock" and x != "Paper" and x != "paper" and x != 'scissors'and x != 'Scissors':
        x = input("Oops, that won't do you any good... ")
    return x 
def play_again():
    play_again = input("Would you guys like to play again? (y/n) ")
    while play_again != "y" and play_again != "n":
        play_again = input("I'm sorry, what was that? (y/n) ")
            if play_again == "y":
                    return check()
        elif play_again == "n":
            print "Thanks for playing!"

def check():
    Score1 = 2
    Score2 = 2
    while Score1 > 0 and Score2 > 0:
        P1 = player_1()
        P2 = player_2()
        if P1.lower() == P2.lower():
            print("it's a tie!")
        elif P1.lower() == "rock" and P2.lower() == "scissors":
            print("Player 1 Wins!")
            Score1 -= 1
        elif P1.lower() == "paper" and P2.lower() == "rock":
            print("Player 1 Wins!")
            Score1 -= 1
        elif P1.lower() == "scissors" and P2.lower() == "paper":
            print("Player 1 Wins!")
            Score1 -= 1
        else:
            print("Player 2 Wins!")
            Score2 -= 1

        if Score1 == 0:
            print("Congratulations Player 1 for winning best out of three!")
        if Score2 == 0:
            print("Congratulations Player 2 for winning best out of three!")
    play_again()        
check()       


main()
```

Comment: Why do you have a return statement right before `elif H1 == 1:`?

Comment: You also have bad indentation in your very first line. Is that in the original code?

Comment: well thank you because you fixed my first problem lol and yes it is the original code but i got messed up when i transferred it to here. the program now runs so thank you again now i just need to figure out the two player mode :D

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you shouldn't be using `elif` and use `if`, because there are no `if` statements above it.

Also, I don't think you need to return your H1 in your function.

Comment: Well,  if it works fine, then you can keep it, but unless you are using the function to determine a value for something else, you don't really need it.